# FileNotFoundException in src/main/resources

Tags: java, maven, filenotfoundexception

i placed a file in my maven project under src/main/resources
the files name is simply temp.txt.

When i try to open the file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("./temp.txt")));
```

I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \temp.txt
```

all files under src/main/resources are placed in the root folder of
the classpath under maven.
So why cant the program find the file here?

Comment: do you need the `'.'`?

Comment: that changes nothing. The '.' just says the current directory. Without '.' is the same like with the '.'.

Comment: try removing it anyways

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're going to package the file in the class path, then read it as such.. from the class path.

Maven Structure

```
src
   main
       resources
               file.txt
```

After it builds, the file gets placed in the root of the class path. So use

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

The `/` in front of `file.txt` will bring you to the root, from whatever package the class is in.

---

**UPDATE**

Test example

```
package com.underdogdevs.stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestResourceFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = TestResourceFile.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: And your file is in `src/main/resources/file.txt`?

Comment: Review your build and verify that the file is copied correctly. Is not there some typo?

Comment: With the `/` = `null`. Without the `/` = `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Gotta say, the statement is dope
"If you're going to package the file in the class path, then read it as such.. from the class path."

Comment: Sorry for now ask this. But If i wanna get more resources. What can I do? because when I can't get classpath or anything when running jar.

Answer (score 6):

just give this as your path:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new 
File("src/main/resources/temp.txt")));
```

Comment: This is not going to work after you export your project. You will no longer have access to the source code (src dir) when the project is deployed. If you are placing files into the resource dir, then they should be read as classpath resources.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem when setting up integration tests in Jenkins. 
The issue was caused by having the job inside a folder with spaces in the name. So instead of having a workspace folder named `foo bar`, Jenkins created `foo%20bar` and the tests all failed with `FileNotFoundException`. 
The solution is just to rename your folder so it doesn't have any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Maven puts the files under `/src/main/resouces/` into the default package of your classpath. Hence you can load through the classloader:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourcesAsStream("temp.txt")
```

For more information see [Class#getResoucesAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: same exception. and all other files i load on the same way and it works perfectly.