# file not found exception in java with maven

Tags: java, maven, exception, logging, filereader

I am trying to read the log file from the directory: src/main/resources/example.log
The file is already there but it throws file not found exception.
Here is my code:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //logfilepath = "src\\main\\resources\\example.log";
        Input input=new CommandLineInput();
        Textfilehandler textfilehandler = new Textfilehandler();
        Log logvariables=new Logvariables();
        Firstreadinglog firstreadinglog = new Firstreadinglog(textfilehandler,logvariables);
        Logfilehandler logfilehandler = null;
        Morereadinglog morereadinglog = new Morereadinglog(textfilehandler,logvariables);

        LogAnalyzerApp app=new LogAnalyzerApp(textfilehandler,firstreadinglog,morereadinglog,input);
        app.show();
    }
}
```

And the error message is:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /example.log (No such file or
> directory) Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length
> 0     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
> at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)     at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)     at
> kln.se.ass2.logfile.Morereadinglog.getcurrentlogstates(Morereadinglog.java:50)
> at kln.se.ass2.LogAnalyzerApp.show(LogAnalyzerApp.java:35)  at
> kln.se.ass2.Main.main(Main.java:29)

I entered the file path as follows:
`src\main\resources\example.log`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundException in src/main/resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547488/filenotfoundexception-in-src-main-resources)

Comment: noo. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Did you try to put the full path of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the full path of the file using resource of Maven that automatically sets the current working directory, then you can just use:

```
File resourcesDirectory = new File("src/main/resources/example.log");
    
String logfilepath = resourcesDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that I use Linux OS. I entered the directory with backslashes as in Windows. Now I figured it out. Thank you.